# Applying both a color and gradient to QPushButton's background

Tags: qt, stylesheet

I need to know if it is at all possible to set a background color with an overlapping gradient on a QPushButton. I've created a round button with an SVG image as it's icon (which is just a white image showing an exclamation mark and a white border). I need the background of the button to be black, and when toggled I need it to display a radial gradient over the black background. The situation I have now just replaces the black background with the gradient:

[image]

The stylesheet I use is as follows:

```
QPushButton{
    background: black;
    border-radius: 25;
    border-color: gray;
}

#alertButton::checked{
    background-color: qradialgradient(cx: 0.5, cy: 0.5, radius: 2, fx: 0.5, fy: 1, stop: 0 rgba(255,30,30,255), stop: 0.2 rgba(255,30,30,144), stop: 0.4 rgba(255,30,30,32));
}
```

So, would it be possible to place the gradient over the black background, instead of it replacing it? If possible by doing this in the stylesheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just adapt the gradient to go from the gradient's color to the background color to have the same effect. So instead of going from red to white, go from red to black.

Comment: That might be the best alternative, I agree. But the main question was rather if it was possible, which I am beginning to doubt.

Comment: The two are really mutually exclusive, and I don't see what the gain of this "feature" you want would be. If a gradient color can have an alpha value, you might be able to pull it off, but it would still be senseless (in this case, if the background is not a solid color, it might make sense).

Comment: My aim was to make the default black background a general layout for every button of that type. The gradient will be different depending on the button's function. I was trying to generalize the layouts. But apparently, this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try subclassing the QAbstractButton and override the `Painter` function to draw a black background.

Comment: I'd rather not do that, as it is the aim to keep things as simple as possible. This means relying mostly on the standard components. It would be a good solution though. Maybe, if it is absolutely necessary, I'll do that.